# Monitor class repeating forever even when simulation has reached $finish

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I made a SystemVerilog testbbench for a simple D flip flop.

Design code:

```
   module dff (dff_if vif);
  
     always@(posedge vif.clk)
       begin
        if(vif.rst == 1'b1)
        vif.dout <= 1'b0;
        else
          vif.dout <= vif.din;
        end
  
    endmodule
```

In the testbench, the monitor class is forever going on even though simulation has reached $finished.

Testbench code:

```
   interface dff_if;
      logic clk;
      logic rst;
      logic din;
      logic dout;
  
      endinterface

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////tran
    class transaction;
      randc bit in;
      bit out;
  
      function transaction copy();
       copy=new();
       copy.in=this.in;
       copy.out=this.out;
      endfunction
  
      function void display(string tag);
       $display("[%s] datain:%d dataout=%d",tag,in,out);
      endfunction
  
    endclass

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////gen

    class generator;
       transaction t;
       mailbox gtd;
       mailbox gts;
       event drvnext; //delete after test
       event done;
  
      function new(mailbox gtd,mailbox gts);
      t=new();
      this.gtd=gtd;
      this.gts=gts;
      endfunction
  
      task run();
        repeat(10) begin
         $display("______________________________________________________________________");
          assert(t.randomize) else $error("[GEN] : RANDOMIZATION FAILED");
         gtd.put(t.copy());
         gts.put(t.copy());
         t.display("GEN");
         @(drvnext);
        end
       ->done;
       $display("DONE");
      endtask
  
      endclass
      ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////drv
      
     class driver;
       virtual dff_if vif;
       transaction t;
       mailbox gtd;
      //event drvnext;
  
       function new(mailbox gtd);
        t=new();
        this.gtd=gtd;
        endfunction
  
      task run();
        forever begin
        @(posedge vif.clk);
        @(posedge vif.clk);
       gtd.get(t);
         vif.din=t.in;
       t.display("DRV");
    
        end
      endtask
     endclass



    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////mon
    class monitor;
     virtual dff_if vif;
     transaction tr;
    mailbox mts;
  event drvnext;
  
  function new(mailbox mts);
    tr=new();
    this.mts=mts;
  endfunction
  
  task run();
  forever begin
    @(posedge vif.clk);
    @(posedge vif.clk);
    tr.out=vif.dout;
      mts.put(tr);
      tr.display("MON");
    ->drvnext;
      
    end
  endtask
endclass
 
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
module tb;
  generator g;
  driver drv;
  monitor mn;
  dff_if vif();
  
  dff dut(vif);
  
  mailbox gtd;
  mailbox gts;
  mailbox mts;
  
  event drvnext;
  event done;
  
  initial begin
    gtd=new();
    gts=new(); 
    mts=new();
    
    g=new(gtd,gts);
    drv=new(gtd);
    mn=new(mts);
    
    g.drvnext=drvnext;
    mn.drvnext=drvnext;
    g.done=done;
    
    drv.vif=vif;
    mn.vif=vif;
    
    fork
    g.run();
    drv.run();
     mn.run();
    join_any
    
    @(done);
    $finish;
    
  end

  
  initial 
    vif.clk=0;
  always #5 vif.clk=~vif.clk;
  
  
endmodule
```

Simulation Output (of some last transactions):

```
# KERNEL: [GEN] datain:0 dataout=0
# KERNEL: [DRV] datain:0 dataout=0
# KERNEL: [MON] datain:0 dataout=1
# KERNEL: _______________________________________________________________________________________
# KERNEL: [GEN] datain:1 dataout=0
# KERNEL: [DRV] datain:1 dataout=0
# KERNEL: [MON] datain:0 dataout=0
# KERNEL: _______________________________________________________________________________________
# KERNEL: [GEN] datain:0 dataout=0
# KERNEL: [DRV] datain:0 dataout=0
# KERNEL: [MON] datain:0 dataout=1
# KERNEL: DONE
# KERNEL: [MON] datain:0 dataout=0
# KERNEL: [MON] datain:0 dataout=0
# KERNEL: [MON] datain:0 dataout=0
# KERNEL: [MON] datain:0 dataout=0
# KERNEL: [MON] datain:0 dataout=0
# KERNEL: [MON] datain:0 dataout=0
# KERNEL: [MON] datain:0 dataout=0
# KERNEL: [MON] datain:0 dataout=0
# KERNEL: [MON] datain:0 dataout=0
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: How do you know it is hitting the $finish?  Maybe put a $display("Finishing"); followed by #1; just before the $finish to verify its reaching the $finish;.

Comment: It is blocked at the `@done`, never executing the `$finish`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a misuse of the `event`.  The event was triggered before you started waiting for it with the `@(done)` statement.  You can detect a previous event with the `wait`/ `triggered` combination.

Change:

```
@(done);
```

to:

```
wait(done.triggered);
```

Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 9.4.4 *Level-sensitive sequence controls*.

Simulation output:

```
...
______________________________________________________________________
[GEN] datain:1 dataout=0
[DRV] datain:1 dataout=0
[MON] datain:0 dataout=0
______________________________________________________________________
[GEN] datain:0 dataout=0
[DRV] datain:0 dataout=0
[MON] datain:0 dataout=1
DONE
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you have `@done` before `$finish`, but you trigger `done` before executing that statement. Event triggers statements must execute *before* statements that wait for the trigger. There is no need for the `event done` You will get out of the `fork/join_any` when the monitor finishes its `for` loop anyways

I strongly discourage the use of the `triggered` method as mentioned in the other answer. It can easily break as your code gets more complex.  Figure out a way not to use events (in this case you don't even need to be using it), or make sure your code executes the `@done` before the `->done`. You could have used `fork/join_none` or used `->>done` instead of `->`